# Setting up OpenALPR with c++, undefined reference.

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, openalpr

I need to integrate OpenALPR library into my c++ program. Unfortunaltely, I can't make linking work.

**openalpr.lib** is in C:\path\to\alpr , **alpr.h** header in C:\path\to\alpr\include  all *.dll files are in catalog with *main* file. 
System Windows7, Compiler Gcc 5.3.

Current build command:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -IC:\path\to\alpr\include -c C:\path\to\project\main.cpp -o obj\main.o

g++ -LC:\path\to\alpr -o bin\test.exe obj\main.o -lopenalpr
```

code:

```
#include <alpr.h>
int main()
{
    alpr::Alpr openalpr("us", "openalpr.conf");
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
undefined reference to `alpr::Alpr::Alpr(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
```

And so on, and so on, plenty of similar 'undefined references'.

OpenALPR library is downloaded in binary version from: 
https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Compilation-instructions-(Windows)

Am I supposed to build library from sources? Maybe I missed something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[GCC5 and the C++11 ABI](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/):

> Users that depend on third-party libraries or plugin interfaces that still use the old ABI can build their code with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and everything should work fine. In most cases, it will be obvious when this flag is needed because of errors from the linker complaining about unresolved symbols involving `__cxx11`.

Try compiling with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.

Comment: `g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0  -g -IC:\alpr\include -c C:\project\main.cpp -o obj\main.o`

Nothing changed.

Comment: @Rajju Have you tried linking after compiling with that command?

Comment: Yes, I delete .o file, compile everything from scratch and then link again (even with passing  -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 as a linker flag too).